# Eslint treating string as array in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code in a React component:

```
<select id='header-color'>
  {
    this.props.colors.map((color, i) => {
      return <option 
        value={color.value} 
        key={i} 
        {this.props.headerColor === color.value ? 'selected' : ''}>{color.name} 
      </option>
    })
  }
</select>
```

Eslint is giving me the following error:

```
Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "..."
```

this.props.headerColor is properly passed into the component, and its value should be a string. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

`selected` is a prop that takes a boolean value. You could change it to the following:

```
<select id="header-color">
  {this.props.colors.map((color, i) => {
    return (
      <option
        value={color.value}
        key={i}
        selected={this.props.headerColor === color.value}
      >
        {color.name}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your syntax to this:

```js
<select id='header-color'>
  {
    this.props.colors.map((color, i) => {
      return <option 
        value={color.value} 
        key={i} 
        selected={this.props.headerColor === color.value}>
          {color.name} 
      </option>
    })
  }
</select>
```

since `selected` is a boolean prop rather than a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to those who responded. These answers were really helpful, and led me to what I believe is an even better solution.

It seems like React really wants us to handle the state of our select using `defaultValue`, with an onChange event handled by a method, like so:

```
<select id='header-color' 
  defaultValue={this.props.headerColor} 
  onChange={this.handleSelectChange}>
  {
    this.props.colors.map((color, i) => {
      return <option value={color.value} key={i}>
        {color.name}
      </option>
    })
  }
</select>
```

For the onChange event, I included this above:

```
constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {selectValue: props.headerColor}
    this.handleSelectChange = this.handleSelectChange.bind(this);
}

handleSelectChange(e) {
  this.setState({selectValue: e.currentTarget.value});
}
```